# Discrete Fourier Transform in Signal Processing - Interpreting graphs of transformed signals

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, homework, fourier

[image]

Given above are the real parts of the signals *I* to *IV*. Which of the following statements are correct?

*(i):* Signal *III* is the result of the discrete Fourier transform of signal *I*. The associated imaginary part is *0*.

*(ii):* Signal *III* is the frequency spectrum of an oscillation with a frequency.

*(iii):* Signal *IV* is the frequency spectrum of an oscillation with *2* different frequencies.

*(iv):* Signal *IV* is the result of the discrete Fourier transform of Signal *III*. The associated imaginary part is *0*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(iii) seems be to correct. Spectrum of two frequencies.

The other choices can be verified,

(i) Fourier transform of $f(t=0)=1$ is 1. So it cannot be graph (iii)

(ii) Signal (iii) is sine wave and there is no spectrum associated with that.

(iv) It's Fourier transform of sine wave (iii) which is

$$f(t)=0.5\cdot \sin(2\pi Ft)$$

and it's transform is

$$\frac{\pi}{i}\left[\delta\left(\omega-2\pi F\right)-\delta\left(\omega+2\pi F\right)\right]$$

Imaginary part is not zero